# Plugins for minifying JS & CSS in Visual Studios

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio-2012, plugins, minify

This is just a general question but are there any Visual Studio plugins that will minify your JS and CSS files on build/deploy?

I search a little bit and found one called Bundler & Minifier but reading the recent reviews, there are many that say the current version is buggy and does not always work. I don't want to risk anything going wrong with my website.

Are there any other plugins out there that you have used consistently and are reliable?

Please let me know!
Thank you.